# Using AVAudioPlayer before navigating with a navigation link navigates back to first page

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avaudioplayer, navigationview

I am building an Alarm App where i use the AVAudioPlayer to setup my Alarm Sound. But for some reason when i setup AVAudioPlayer and navigate to the next view it instantly navigates back to the first page in the NavigationView. I currently have the following code:

```js
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import UserNotifications

struct SetAlarmView: View {

  @State
  var date = Date()
  @EnvironmentObject
  var alarm: Alarm
  @State
  var tagSelection: Int ? = nil

  func setAlarm(secondsToAlarm: Double) - > Void {
    let sound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "simple", ofType: "mp3")
    let player =
      try !AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: sound!))
    player.play(atTime: player.deviceCurrentTime + secondsToAlarm)
  }

  func setupAlarmSession() {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
      try audioSession.setCategory(.playback, options:          [.defaultToSpeaker, .duckOthers])
      try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {}
  }

  @ViewBuilder
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      DatePicker("", selection: $date).labelsHidden().onAppear {
        self.setupAlarmSession()
      }
      Spacer()

      NavigationLink(destination: ActiveAlarmView(), tag: 2, selection: $tagSelection) {
        Button(action: {
          let secondsToAlarm = self.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
          self.setAlarmNotification(secondsToAlarm: secondsToAlarm)
          self.setAlarm(secondsToAlarm: secondsToAlarm)
          self.tagSelection = 2
        }) {
          HStack {
            Image(systemName: "clock.fill").font(.title)
            Text("Set Alarm").fontWeight(.semibold).font(.title)
          }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding().foregroundColor(.white)
            .background(Color.purple)
            .cornerRadius(40)
            .padding(20)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```